# python: convert ascii character to boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, ascii

I have a character. I want to represent its ascii value as a numpy array of booleans.
This works, but seems contorted. Is there a better way?

```
bin_str = bin(ord(mychar))
bool_array = array([int(x)>0 for x in list(bin_str[2:])], dtype=bool)
```

for

```
mychar = 'd'
```

the desired resulting value for bool_array is

```
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Can you check this, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/

Comment: That looks like the wrong tool (meant for interactions with binary files, not conversions within python code), and even if it would do what I want, importing a c-based module seems like a worse solution than what I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less the same thing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mychar = 'd'
>>> np.array(list(np.binary_repr(ord(mychar), width=4))).astype('bool')
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Is it less contorted?

Comment: it's easier for me to read, and gives the right result, so, yes. thank you.

Comment: also, the width=4 argument is unnecessary, so np.array(list(np.binary_repr(ord(mychar)))).astype('bool') works

Comment: ok, this is closest to my eventual solution, which doesn't use any other numpy functions aside from array itself: np.array(list(bin(ord('d'))))[2:].astype(bool)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the bits from a uint8 array directly using [`np.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html):

```
np.unpackbits(np.array(ord(mychar), dtype=np.uint8))
```

**EDIT**: To get only the 7 relevant bits in a boolean array:

```
np.unpackbits(np.array(ord(mychar), dtype=np.uint8)).astype(bool)[1:]
```

Comment: this does not exactly do what I want - it is an array of numbers, not booleans. to get the boolean result I want I need to do array([x>0 for x in np.unpackbits(np.array(ord(mychar), dtype=np.uint8))]). And still that's not quite right because it prepends a False to get the uint8 out of ascii's 7 bits.

Comment: though i didn't previously know about unpackbits, which looks useful for other problems, so thank you.

Comment: ah, thanks. that does look a little cleaner than @tiago 's solution.